# call default "New Account" Action in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

In aura lightning component we can call the default create new account action by using

```
var createAcountEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createAcountEvent .setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Account",
});
createAcountEvent .fire();
```

What can we use in lwc? I tried the following but not working...

```
createNewEvent() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: "standard__objectPage",
      attributes: {
        objectApiName: "Account",
        actionName: "new"
      },
      state: {
        nooverride: "1"
      }
    });
  }
```

I have also imported:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from "lightning/pageReferenceUtils";
```

Any ideas ???

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that this does not seem to work. I have a button that calls this function and when i click it, although the function gets called, nothing happes... It does not popup any window for new record creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Giorgos have done below:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';


export default class MyCustomElement extends **NavigationMixin(LightningElement)** {

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. It'd help if you could flesh this out with just a sentence or so to state what the problem is in words, so that readers can put this code snippet in context.